# session is not working in middleware laravel 5.2

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am trying to create a middleware that counts how many times a user has accessed my site in a period of time. I tried to use laravel session in my middleware. Here is my code:

```
class SessionHandler {
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    if(!Session::has('count')){
        Session::set('count', 1);
        Session::save();
    }else{
        $numOfVisits = Session::get('count');
        $numOfVisits++;
        Session::set('count', $numOfVisits);
        Session::save();
    }
    dd(Session::get('count'));
}
}
```

in my app\Http\kernel.php I added the middleware after SessionStart middle ware:

```
protected $middleware = [
    ....
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    ....
    \Dideo\Http\Middleware\SessionHandler::class,
];
```

but every time I refresh the page I get the response is 1. It means that the session is not set.

How can I work with session in laravel middleware?

[EDIT]

I found that the problem is with EncryptCookie middleware. My session driver is database and every time I refresh the page a record is added in session table.

When I turn off EncryptCookie middleware the problem is fixed.

Comment: Shouldn't it be -> `if(!Session::has('count'))` (if there is no value instantiate with `1`?

Comment: fixed it but still got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong "IF" condition. You are setting count to 1 every time. And set to "count + 1" if it's first visit (so it's also 1). That's what you're doing:

```
if (isset($a)) {
   $a = 1; //set $a to 1
} else {
   $a = $a + 1; //set $a to 1 again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a small logical problem in your code, I would do it this way

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    $value = 1; //Initially it is 1
    if(Session::has('count')){ //If a previous save has been made take that value
        $value = Session::get('count') + 1; //add
    }// do not need an else block, first call will save value of 1
    Session::set('count', $value); //Set it to 1 (first call) or the incremented value
    Session::save();
    dd(Session::get('count'));
}
```

Comment: I fixed the logical error in my code
the problem is with the laravel session